# django cache not update

Tags: python, django, caching

my django database have a Mode name Photo. and the View have a method get_photos witch will list all photos . and have a upload_photo to add a Photo to Table.

the problem is say .

1. now i have 5 photos , and i call get_photos will return a list contain 5 photos .
2. i upload a photo and success
3. and i call get_photos , i will return 5 photos sometime , and 6 photos sometimes .
4. i restart the django server . i will got 6 photos always.

how can i solve the problem . thanks .

bellow is the view method of get_all_photos

```
@csrf_exempt
def photos(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        start_index = request.POST['start_index']
    else:
        start_index = request.GET['start_index']

    start_index=int(start_index.strip())
    photos_count = Photo.objects.all().count()

    allphotos = Photo.objects.all().order_by('-publish_time')[start_index: start_index+photo_page_step]

    retJson = {}
    retJson["code"]=200 #ok

    data = {}
    data["count"]=photos_count
    photos = []
    for p in allphotos:
        photo = json_entity.from_photo(p,True);
        photos.append(photo)
    data["photos"]=photos
    retJson["data"]=data

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(retJson), mimetype="application/json")
```

Comment: Please post some code. At least the code of the view and get_photos. No one will be able to help you without more details.

Comment: i think it not the problem of view method , i think i should make some django configure , but i don't know .

Comment: Why do you think it is caching issue? Did you configure caching?

Comment: no , i have not configure that .

Comment: Do you have a custom manager on the Photo class?

Comment: yes , i have rewrite objects to another manger .

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do a couple of things here. Firstly you could add the @never_cache decorator to your get_photos view:

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache

@never_cache
def get_photos(request):
    ...
```

This will never cache the page which might be ok for your situation. Alternatively you could cache the photos and then when you upload a new photo, expire the cache:

```
from django.core.cache import cache

def get_photos(request):
    photos = cache.get('my_cache_key')
    if not photos:
        # get photos here
        cache.set('my_cache_key', photos)
    ....



def upload_photo(request):
    # save photo logic here
    cache.set('my_cache_key', None) # this will reset the cache
```

It might be that the never_cache solution is sufficient but I wanted to include the above as a hint :)